Reference counting for sqllite database
I am using javascript and node express with async/await. So there is only one thread/process running, but the way it executes is not straightforward.
Asynchronous methods may request rows from an sqllite database. I am using this npm package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite
If simply opening and closing the database inside the async methods, like this
async function request() {
    var db = await sqlite.open({
        filename: "filename.db",
        mode: sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY,
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    })
    //-- do something, like this
    const stmt = await db.prepare("SELECT 1");
    const rows = await stmt.all();
    await stmt.finalize();
    //-- then close
    await db.close();
}

This throws "SQLITE_BUSY" errors. So I made functions like this to open/close the database:
var inUse = false;

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function openDb() {
  while (inUse) {
    await timeout(50)
  }
  inUse = true;
  return await sqlite.open({
    filename: "filename.db",
    mode: sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY,
    driver: sqlite3.Database
  })
}

async function closeDb(db) {
  await db.close();
  inUse = false;
}

And then call these functions to open/close the database. But this only allows one async method to use the database at a time, while other requests need to wait. I think it might be possible to allow several "threads" to share the database with reference counting somehow, but don't know exactly how to do it.

To manage concurrent database access with SQLite using reference counting, you can implement the Reference Counting approach.
let referenceCount = 0;
let dbInstance = null;

async function openDb() {
  while (referenceCount > 0 && dbInstance === null) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50)); // Wait if DB is in use
  }
  
  if (dbInstance === null) {
    dbInstance = await sqlite.open({
      filename: "filename.db",
      mode: sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY,
      driver: sqlite3.Database
    });
  }
  
  referenceCount++;
  return dbInstance;
}

async function closeDb() {
  referenceCount--;
  if (referenceCount === 0 && dbInstance) {
    await dbInstance.close();
    dbInstance = null;
  }
}

async function request() {
  const db = await openDb();
  const stmt = await db.prepare("SELECT 1");
  const rows = await stmt.all();
  await stmt.finalize();
  console.log(rows);
  await closeDb();
}

This allows multiple concurrent reads (or operations) and ensures the database is only closed once all operations are complete.

Would this not let multiple "threads" open the same database, with resource leaks? For instance, if the first thread gets to the line "dbInstance = await sqlite.open({", then dbInstance is still === null while waiting for the database to open. If another thread, passes the same checks and gets to the same line, dbInstance would be overwritten by whichever thread returned from the await last, leaving one open connection
